# How to replicate clipping masks in css / position absolute and overflow hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get this result in html and css:
[image]

A grid where cells act as a mask for a yellow circle
(please ignore the dotted borders they are just to aid in css,I had to photoshop in the white spaces)

So my approach was to make 9 floating divs and in each one a circle, and then position the circles absolutely to the parent <= the container that holds the 9 divs, so that they are all in the same place. And then use overflow:hidden on the 9 divs.

Here is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gridCircle.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
div#container {
    width: 24em;
    height: 24em;
    border: solid;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 8em;
    position: relative;
}

.square {
    border: dotted 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: 1.4%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 100000em;
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    top: 2em;
    left: 2em;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

here is the result I get from this:

[image]

The problem is that I can't use overflow:hidden if I don't put position:relative on the 9 divs. And doing so would misplace the circles, because now they are positioned relatively to the small divs

How can I achieve my goal? Can my approach be fixed or should I do it in a totally different way?

PS: I can do it in JS using `transform:translate`, but I got a feeling this is doable via css.

Comment: I'm aware this is probably not the solution you are looking for, but.. http://jsbin.com/zodomu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Toby very neat trick actually, as always with css you have to trick it. Problem is with responsiveness. Any idea if I can make that shadow you added change width dynamically?

Comment: absolutely - you're using ems and % for sizing right now, but if you switch to use only `rem` or `%` for sizing, it should scale. One little added bonus is that because it's a shadow on each square, it's not that big a deal if they overlap, so I'd probably extend the shadow by more than the exact amount required. Additionally, you can set `overflow: hidden;` on the outer div to prevent any unwated effects on the border.

Comment: Also worth noting, if you went with this solution you really only need one `.circle`, the rest only overlap the first one.